# Making a 3D polygon with 3D view in qgis 3.4

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, 3d-map

I tried to make a 3D map in QGIS 3.4, using the "3D view" function.

[image]

However, as I change the 3D property the polygon have not changed.
I tried this with a basic ESRI Shapefile that I made.
I also change the crs to "Sphere_Cylindrical_Equal_Area" thinking maybe the CRS need to be in meters and not degrees, but it did not help.

What is needed to make the layer display into a 3D display?

Comment: I see from the yellow button right of the 'Height' field that you have enabled *data defined override* for this parameter. Did you connect the height to an attribute or maybe to an expression that does not work properly? What happens if you turn of *data defined override* and use 'Extrusion' instead?

Comment: I turn the "data defined override" off, it did not change the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the layer properties you just define how a layer behaves in a 3D map view. At first, you observe no changes in the map view (which is 2D). In an example I have defined *data defined override* for 'Extrusion' with an expression like `rand(5, 40)` randomly generating heights between 5 and 40 meters. Then add a new 3D Map view (View | New 3D Map View) and you should see something like shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

One of the great features in QGIS 3 is the ability to manage a variety of map views at a time where 2D map view can even synchronize with each other.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Maybe there is anymore steps at this process?

Comment: Is there a need for some specific CRS?