# 3D View is not available in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, 3d, linux

I'm running QGIS 3.4 Madeira on Linux Mint 17. The upgrade to 3.4 seemed to go smoothly, but there is no *"3D View"* option in my "View" menu.

Is there something else I need to do? FWIW QGIS 3 J's works OK.

Comment: 3D requires Qt 5.9 and above. QGIS 3.4 Madeira doesn't have it.

Comment: Yet there are plenty of pages showcasing or with tutorials eg  https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2018/10/17/qgis3d-new-features-qgis3-4/  or here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302202/making-a-3d-polygon-with-3d-view-in-qgis-3-4 so is it just the Linux version that doesn't have Qt 5.9?

Comment: Your QGIS 3.4 Madeira probably doesn't have it. Click on Help -> About where you can corroborate that ('Compiled against Qt', 'Running against Qt'). By the way, latest release of Linux Mint is 19.2 (you have old 17 version),

Answer (score 3):

As touched on in the comments above, your distro has a very outdated version of the Qt libraries where required 3D functionality is not available. You need to update your distro to remedy this.

Comment: Thanks. This'll be the shove I need to make that happen. I was planning a PC revamp & have been putting it off