# Setting the 3d view function for a polygon layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, 3d, 3d-model

I am trying to create a 3d model of an archaeological site on QGIS. I had some contourlines, I made them polygons using the "polygonize" plugin and I categorized the polygons with a colour scale according to the altimetry value of each polygon.

[image: style categorised by elevation]

At this point I used the 3d view in the layer properties panel to get a 3d view of the "polygons overlapping" effect. The value of the extrusion is the one found in the ELEV_2 field (i.e. the value of the height of each polygon).

[image: Attributes table]

[image: Settings in the 3d view function]

The result is this:

[image: result]

There are two questions:

1. How do I keep the colour scale I used for the 2d symbology?
2. Is there a way to decrease the height of the base of the model?

I have already used Qgis2threejis. Unfortunately every time I try to open this layer with this plugin the pc freezes.

I have already tried this solution but applied to my case it does not respect the height increase of the polygons [Jochen Schwarze's solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302202/making-a-3d-polygon-with-3d-view-in-qgis-3-4)

Comment: Did you check if the polygons are vaild? How about creating a raster out of the polygons (rasterize)?