# Adding z dimensions to a Polygon

Tags: qgis, dem, topography, 3d-model, z-value

I have a polygon (vector file) which has a base z location from a raster file, however it is still a flat shape.
Is there a way I could add a z dimension to this vector file so it covers a 3-dimensional space?
I believe I may need to convert this vector into a raster, but I am not sure.

Comment: You have the z value as an attribute?

Comment: Yes I do. I have both the base of the polygon z values and the top of the polygon z values (+6 meters above the base). Apologies if it should be straightforward, I am very new to experimenting in this dimension.

Comment: Is [Set Z Value](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissetzvalue) what you are looking for?

Comment: This is where I'm a little confused. I have used the 'Drape (set z values from raster)' operation to give my polygon a base z value, but I want the polygon to be a 3-dimensional shape that's height is 6 meters above this. From what I understand 'Set Z value' would overwrite the drape operation, whereas I would like a base (at raster level) and a top (raster level + 6) z value. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: I dont think you can create a 3D polygon. See [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302202/making-a-3d-polygon-with-3d-view-in-qgis-3-4) if it is only for visualization. If you want to "raise" the polygon I think you should add 6 to your raster using raster calculator, then drape

Comment: Okay, no worries. Thank you very much for your help and suggestions! :)